# What is the purpose of the brown pads on this PCB?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

[image]

This PCB has wire connections to external coils that are soldered to pads on the board. Each of the connections has a patch of brown material carefully placed in between the two pads. What is the brown stuff and what function does it serve?

Guesses:

1. The brown stuff is an extra heavy duty resist to ensure that no solder bridges form between the pads when the wires are soldered on. This is plausible, but the pads are far enough apart that bridging seems unlikely.
2. There are versions of the board that have connectors for the coil connections rather than having the wires directly soldered to the pads. The brown stuff is a heat activated adhesive that is laid down to bond these connectors. The version of the board that I have does not have connectors, so the adhesive is unused.
3. Some kind of spark suppression for flyback kick from the coils?  Like a poor man's spark barrier?
4. Exclude condensation or dirt from that spot?
5. Physically prevent a short from errant metal falling on top of the pads? The blob acts like a little fulcrum so that a flat piece can't touch both at once?

Here is the whole board with 6 of these blobbed connections:

[image]

Comment: Really? This is a very high volume, low cost board. Would they really add an extra process step to the line for batches that would never use it? Wouldn't they wait to apply the adhesive until a batch was destined for the connectorized version?

Comment: Part number? The datasheet might require it.

Comment: Part number and data sheet for what part? The blob is sitting between two pads. The pads are connected to lead wires from custom wound coils.

Comment: So the pads don't have a commercial part in mind? I find that hard to believe

Comment: Nope, they are each connected directly to about 50 turns of ~30 gauge enameled wire. The coils are the transmitter side of an inductive power transfer system.

Comment: The board must be designed for connectors along the edges. It seems they've dedicated a lot of space to just some wires, it could have been made a lot smaller without connectors.

Comment: Something to do with creepage distance maybe?  Those don't look like high-voltage wires, but if they're coils, there might be nasty transients to worry about...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an epoxy adhesive e.g Surface Mount Adhesives (SMA) for SMD components. It's typically used in surface mount Printed Circuit Board (PCB) assemblies to hold the passive, (and sometimes active), components on to the bottom side of the board during wave soldering. It can also be used to increase the thermal conductivity from the component to the PCB for better heat transfer.

If you look closely at the board you may notice that other SMD components on this same side of the board are glued in place with the epoxy. For example look at two other non-populated sites at J1 and J2. You can see some of the brown material there too:

[image]

The process being used to apply the adhesive could be using a screening procedure that was designed do the whole bottom of the assembly at once. And rather than having several screens only one is used despite the component population configuration.

Comment: Adhesive is also often used for heavy components like inductors. Heavy components cannot be retained by the viscosity and cohesive forces of the solder paste even when the PCB is moved very slowly and gently during handling.

Comment: Makes sense. There are actually several though-hole components mounted on the bottom of the board, so perhaps they gluing the SMD parts to the top of the board and then running the whole thing face down though a wave solder process. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of this brown pad in the picture is none. I'll explain.

As the comments and Martin's answer say correctly, the brown mass is epoxy glue. And it is correct that normally it would keep a SMD component in place if it was soldered by wave, overhead or if the component was a heavy one. The silkscreen print suggests, that the glue is part of a SMD-decal.

But as the OP states, the PCB is a very high volume, low cost board. And the inductors can't be placed on the PCB as they have another purpose dependin on their position elsewhere.

So my theory is as follows:
A lazy PCB designer made a schematic with his favourite EDA-system. Had to enter the inductors, hence took a standard symbol (and the next-best decal) and assigned a value. Perhaps to feed a simulator plugin inside his/her EDA system. Layout phase was approaching, and they normally would have to split the schematic and insert connectors. The electronic and mechanical designers agreed to solder the coil directly onto the PCB which solved many problems (e.g. finding a connector capable of getting grip on single wire 0.08 mm² copper or so). The last task was to replace the SMD-inductor decal with a pair of solder pads.

But miraculously the inductor pad already provided everything needed for that. Two pads with sufficient distance for manual soldering, and a meaningful silkscreen print. As the few micrograms of wasted epoxy won't change the bom cost the designers called it a day.

Comment: If I don't find a conectorized variant then we may have to concede to the Lazy Engineer Hypothesis!

Comment: I will make the observation that the "inconvenient yet necessary mounting holes" resulted in the alteration of the footprint for L3 and L4 on the pad and glue layer, but not the silkscreen.

Comment: @W5VO: This change was perhaps done in the gerber files. Maybe even at the PCB manufacturers site after checking design rules.